# Create an Excel Output Xamarin. Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, export-to-excel

I'm trying to get an Excel output from my program with a Butten click.
I have multiple list views with Entries in them that user can define the values.
I don't want to use syncfusion because of license issues!

Here it is my listview:

```
<ListView x:Name="LL" Grid.Row="3"   ItemsSource="{Binding energy}" HeightRequest="300" >
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>

                                    <Grid  Padding="5" BackgroundColor="White" RowSpacing="40" >
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                        <Label x:Name="label" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding EE}" FontSize="18"  TextColor="Black" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
                                        <Entry TextChanged="Entry_TextChanged" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Keyboard="Numeric" Placeholder=". . . . . . . ." Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Beige" WidthRequest="80" />
                                        <Entry TextChanged="Entry_TextChanged_1" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Keyboard="Numeric" Placeholder=". . . . . . . ." Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Beige" WidthRequest="80"/>
                                        <Entry TextChanged="Entry_TextChanged_2" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Keyboard="Numeric" Placeholder=". . . . . . . ." Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Beige" WidthRequest="80"/>
                                        <BoxView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Black" WidthRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                        <BoxView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Black" WidthRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                        <BoxView Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Black" WidthRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>


                                    </Grid>

                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

Comment: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Comment: Also, check out this: https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML

Comment: tanx all. Hi Hadi will you be able to help me with this project? we can manage some kind of a deal.

Comment: To communicate with them, type a message containing @HadiFooladiTalari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether you want to save the value in three entries. So I create three properties E1, E2, E3. For the code below, it only save the EE property value into excel.

**Install `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` package in NuGet.**

**Install Excel app in your device.**

Xaml:

Code behind:

```
 public partial class Page15 : ContentPage
{
    public Page15()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BindingContext = new ExportingExcelViewModel();
    }

    private void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Entry_TextChanged_1(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Entry_TextChanged_2(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
public class EEModel
{
    public string EE { get; set; }
    public string E1 { get; set; }
    public string E2 { get; set; }
    public string E3 { get; set; }
}

public class ExcelStructure
{
    public List<string> Headers { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public List<List<string>> Values { get; set; } = new List<List<string>>();
}

public class ExcelService
{
    private string AppFolder => Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);

    private Cell ConstructCell(string value, CellValues dataTypes) =>
        new Cell()
        {
            CellValue = new CellValue(value),
            DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(dataTypes)
        };

    public string GenerateExcel(String fileName)
    {
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MONO_URI_DOTNETRELATIVEORABSOLUTE", "true");

        // Creating the SpreadsheetDocument in the indicated FilePath
        var filePath = Path.Combine(AppFolder, fileName);
        var document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(Path.Combine(AppFolder, fileName), SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

        var wbPart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
        wbPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

        var part = wbPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        part.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

        //  Here are created the sheets, you can add all the child sheets that you need.
        var sheets = wbPart.Workbook.AppendChild
            (
               new Sheets(
                        new Sheet()
                        {
                            Id = wbPart.GetIdOfPart(part),
                            SheetId = 1,
                            Name = "Employment"
                        }
                    )
            );


        // Just save and close you Excel file
        wbPart.Workbook.Save();
        document.Close();
        // Dont't forget return the filePath
        return filePath;
    }

    public void InsertDataIntoSheet(string fileName, string sheetName, ExcelStructure data)
    {
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MONO_URI_DOTNETRELATIVEORABSOLUTE", "true");

        using (var document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, true))
        {
            var wbPart = document.WorkbookPart;
            var sheets = wbPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().
                         Elements<Sheet>().FirstOrDefault().
                         Name = sheetName;

            var part = wbPart.WorksheetParts.First();
            var sheetData = part.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();

            var row = sheetData.AppendChild(new Row());

            foreach (var header in data.Headers)
            {
                row.Append(ConstructCell(header, CellValues.String));
            }

            foreach (var value in data.Values)
            {
                var dataRow = sheetData.AppendChild(new Row());

                foreach (var dataElement in value)
                {
                    dataRow.Append(ConstructCell(dataElement, CellValues.String));
                }
            }
            wbPart.Workbook.Save();
        }
    }
}

public class ExportingExcelViewModel
{
    public ICommand ExportToExcelCommand { private set; get; }
    private ExcelService excelService;
    public ObservableCollection<EEModel> energy { get; set; }


    public ExportingExcelViewModel()
    {
        energy = new ObservableCollection<EEModel>
        {
            new EEModel{  EE="A",  },
            new EEModel{  EE="B",  },
            new EEModel{  EE="C",  },
            new EEModel{  EE="D",  },
            new EEModel{  EE="E",  },

        };

        ExportToExcelCommand = new Command(async () => await ExportToExcel());
        excelService = new ExcelService();
    }

    async Task ExportToExcel()
    {
        var fileName = "Employ.xlsx";
        string filepath = excelService.GenerateExcel(fileName);

        var data = new ExcelStructure
        {
            Headers = new List<string>() { "EE", "E1", "E2" }
        };

        foreach (var item in energy)
        {
            data.Values.Add(new List<string>() { item.EE, item.E1, item.E2 });
        }

        excelService.InsertDataIntoSheet(filepath, "Employ", data);

        await Launcher.OpenAsync(new OpenFileRequest()
        {
            File = new ReadOnlyFile(filepath)
        });
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: @WendyZangMSFT Thank you for your response, I will try it and send result.

Comment: beautiful it works perfectly, thank you alot @WendyZang-MSFT . How can i define the rows or the color of the rows? And will you be able to help me with my project ? we can have a deal